# free form date field

Tags: html

I was reading this archive on joel on sw http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/TwoStories.html

here he mentions he wanted to make a date field free format. Then I thought how would someone do that? ofcourse search in gmail does it.

has anyone implemented this before? and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could check out any of the following date parsing implementations

- Google's parsedatetime on google code (http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/)
- python-dateutil (http://labix.org/python-dateutil)
- javascript lib (http://www.datejs.com/)
- perl (http://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Flexible)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a very nice implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have users both side of the Atlantic you'll need to prevent 09/10/11 style dates explicitly as much confusion will happen - either require the month in letters or use a drop-down for it and abandon free-form.
Remember 09/11 is the ninth of November in Europe.  Using an IP address's location to disambiguate fails because Europeans and Americans can cross the Atlantic!